# MobX,Store Is Not Available, Make Sure It Is Provided By Some Provider

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobx, state-management

NOTE: Even there are some similar questionswith mine, there is no satisfied answer in my case  !!!

In my react-native project, I use mobx as state management. Some part of my  Login.js file is like following:

```
       export default class Login extends React.Component {
          @observable isLogged = true;
        .
        .
        .
        .
    render() {
        return (
          <Provider store = {Login}>
            <View style={styles.container}>

            <TextInput
              style={styles.input}
              placeholder='Kullanıcı Adı'
              autoCapitalize="none"
              placeholderTextColor='white'
              onChangeText={val => this.onChangeText('username', val)}


       /> 
        .
        .
        .
```

And some part of my App.js file is like following:

```
    .
    .
    .

    @inject('store')
    @observer
    export default class App extends React.Component{
      // @action(self =>({
      //   changeControl(){console.log("CHANGE CONTROL CALISTI")}
      // }))  

      state = {
      control : false
     }
     render(){

        console.log("ISLOGGED DEGERI:" ,Login.isLogged)

        if (this.props.store.isLogged)
        {
          return (
            <AppDrawerNavigatorLogged/ >
          );
        }
        else
        {
          return (
            <AppDrawerNavigatorNotLogged/ >
          );
        }

      }

    }
    .
    .
    .
```

As it seems, I have a observable variable which is isLogged, and I use a Provider and a store in the Login.js file, and I want to use the isLogged observable variable in my App.js file. However even I use a Provider in the Login.js file, I get an error which is like following:

**Error: MobX injector: Store 'store' is not available! Make sure it is provided by some Provider.**

Is there anyone who has encounter with this problem or have any idea?
Thank you...

Comment: Where is the store?
You have to create the store that contains the observable `isLogged` and then pass it to the provider: https://mobx.js.org/best/store.html

Comment: @AlessandroBottamedi, I am new in the react-native and mobx.  I confused to write the code from my editor to here, I have edited the <Provider> Part. the store is Login component. Still it is not working?Is there any idea about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seem you are missing some core concepts of `mobx` and `mobx-react`. I would recommend to to firstly fix some errors:

- `<Provider>` component should wrap your whole application. In most cases it is around `<App>` component (`<Provider store={loginStore}><App/></Provider>`)
- `Login` in your case is a `React.Component` - this is not right. You need to create a `Login` class and pass an instance of it to `Provider`

Example:

```
class Login {
    @observable isLogged = true;

    // some methods for log in
}

const loginStore = new Login();

class App extends React.Component {
...

   render(){
       return (
           <Provider store={loginStore}>
               <App />
           </Provider>
       ) 
   }
}
```